# How to create a bitmap without image?

Tags: android, bitmap

I have to create a small round bitmap. But I don't have the image. How to do that? I can't use

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
Path path = new Path();
path.addCircle(((float) targetWidth - 1) / 2,((float) targetHeight - 1) / 2,(Math.min(((float) 60), ((float) targetHeight)) / 2),Path.Direction.CCW);
```

as I don't have image. I know how to convert an image to a bitmap but don't know how to create new bitmap I have tried resizing bitmap image without loosing its quality and converting the bitmap using existing images.

Comment: how to create a Bitmap?  Bitmap.createBitmap()

Comment: Thanks. And one more doubt is how to draw a bitmap on an existing bitmap?

Comment: read Canvas documentation

Comment: @pskink  I am new to android can u please telme in detail. My requirement is I have an app icon and my device doesnt support badge count so i have to draw a bitmap over the app shortcut icon to display the count so please help me for the same

Comment: did you read Canvas documentation?

Comment: [link]http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html went thru this

Comment: and didn't you find any word "Bitmap"?

Comment: I found but I want to draw a small cirle at top right corner of an image I am not getting it If I draw a bit map it is ovwrlapping the image.. What I want is bitmap above the image

Comment: so what Canvas method did you use to draw a Bitmap?

Comment: `public Bitmap createBitMap() {
  Bitmap  bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(30, 30, Config.ARGB_8888);
  Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
  final int color = 0xff424242;
  final Paint paint = new Paint();
  final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());    
  paint.setAntiAlias(true);
  canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
  paint.setColor(color);
  canvas.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2,
    bitmap.getWidth() / 2, paint);
  paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
  canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
  return bitmap;
 }`

Comment: you create a canvas based on bitmap,  then you want to draw the same bitmap into itself,  it has no sense...  you need to draw some other bitmap on that canvas

Comment: no not like that .. above bitmap should be drawn at the right corner of a drawable image. so how to draw over it and how to put it in the exact corner.

Comment: what bitmap? its empty bitmap, you want to draw an empty bitmap?

Answer (score 0):

```
*private Bitmap processingBitmap(int count, Bitmap bm){
        int colorCode = 0xffEC5F08;
        int color = 0xffe2986a;
        Bitmap srcBitMap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm.getWidth()+12, bm.getHeight()+10,  Config.ARGB_8888);
        Paint   paint =new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        RectF rect = new RectF(bm.getWidth()-25, bm.getHeight()-70,bm.getWidth()+10,bm.getHeight()-40);
        Paint circlePaint = new Paint();
        circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        circlePaint.setShader(new RadialGradient(srcBitMap.getWidth() / 2, srcBitMap.getHeight() / 2,
                srcBitMap.getHeight() / 3, color, colorCode, TileMode.MIRROR));

        Paint outCircle = new Paint(); 
        outCircle.setStyle(Style.STROKE);  
        outCircle.setColor(Color.WHITE); 
        outCircle.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        outCircle.setAntiAlias(true);
        outCircle.setStrokeWidth(3.5f);
        Paint textPaint = new Paint(); 
        textPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);  
        textPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE); 
        textPaint.setTextSize(15); 
        textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        textPaint.setFakeBoldText(true);
        Paint borderPaint = new Paint();
        borderPaint.setStrokeWidth(3f);
        borderPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        borderPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        borderPaint.setStrokeWidth(3f);
        Rect  drawRect = new Rect(0, srcBitMap.getWidth(), srcBitMap.getWidth(), 0);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(srcBitMap);
        canvas.drawRect(drawRect, paint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bm, 0, 8, null);
        canvas.drawOval(rect, outCircle);
        canvas.drawOval(rect, circlePaint);
        canvas.drawText(Integer.toString(count), bm.getWidth()-8.2f, bm.getHeight()/3.25f, textPaint);

        return srcBitMap;
    }*
```